# File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory

Tags: 7

I'm work on updates modules in my drupal site. When i access `localhost/authorize.php` after linked in config, i recieve this:

```
Update failed! See the log below for more information. Your site is still in maintenance mode.
```

the log is...

```
views

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/views

views_bulk_operations

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/views_bulk_operations

webform

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/webform

jquery_update

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/jquery_update

simplenews

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/simplenews

entityreference

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/entityreference

ctools

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/sites/all/modules/ctools

entity

    Error installing / updating
    File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to change to directory /drupal/sites/all/modules/entity
```

I have tried to fix permissions in folder using:
`sudo chmod a+w` and
`sudo chown root sites/default` and `chmod 777` , every using folder sites/default and sites/all/modules, but i canot successfuly updates my modules using ftp and automatic.... how i fix this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your `chown` command recursively, and also assign an explicit user and your web server's group, like so: `sudo chown my_user:www-data sites/all/* -R` where `my_user` is your id and `www-data` is your web server's group. This will recursively apply ownership to your entire directory tree.

It might also be worth pointing out that you mention assigning ownership and privileges to `sites/default`, but your error messages indicate that the problem is in `sites/all`. :-)

In my experience, failed uploads or updates are almost always due to incorrect ownership.